# Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set. Show that the set of accumulation points of $M$ is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis

Q: Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set. Show that the set of accumulation points of $M$ is a closed set.

---

My book defines an accumulation point $x_{0} \in M$ as:

$\forall$ $ h>0$, $M\cap$ $U_{h}(x_{0})\backslash\{x_{0}\} \neq \emptyset$

So basically any neighborhood around the accumulation point contains at least one element of $M$.

---

How would I go about proving the set of all accumlation points is closed?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of closed?

Comment: $M$ is closed iff $M^{c}$ is open. M is open if for any $m \in M, \exists h>0$ s.t. $U_{h}(m) \subset M$

Comment: @dawgchow: Can you solve it now from the hint below?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Let $E$ denote the set of accumulation points of $M$. Let $x \in E^c$. Suppose that there exists no neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap E = \emptyset$. Try to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=\{\text{accumulation points of }M\}^c$; you want to show that it is an open set. Let $c\in C$. Since $c$ is *not* an accumulation point of $M$, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\bigl(M\cap(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)\bigr)\setminus\{c\}=\emptyset$. But then $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$ contains no accumulation point of $M$. In fact, if $x\in(c-\varepsilon,c)$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$ and therefore$$\bigl(M\cap(x-\delta,x+\delta)\bigr)\setminus\{x\}\subset\bigl(M\cap(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)\bigr)\setminus\{c\}=\emptyset.$$The case in which $x\in(c,c+\varepsilon)$ is similar.

So, this proves that $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)\subset C$. Therefore, $C$ is an open set.